# Google Location APIs, which one for my needs?

Tags: javascript, api, location

I wish to write some Javascript that will allow a user to enter a location using Autocomplete and using one of Google's many location related APIs. The input from the user will be a **Town** or **City** name within a country, a **Road** name, a full address (**Door number** + Road name), a **Place** name (such as a restaurant) or a **Zipcode**.

With this input I wish to capture the **latitude** and **longitude**, and if available a provided Zip/postal code.

There are a myriad of APIs available for this subject and I have tried playing with google.maps.Geocoder which provided sometimes erroneous results (passing random Lat/Long information for towns that autocomplete itself correctly provided). Please could you advise which one would be best for my needs.

Thank you

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

```
    var lat=0, lng=0;

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", index, false);

    function index(){
        initialMap();
        $("#pac-input").on("change",function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                address = $("#pac-input").val();
                nativegeocoder.forwardGeocode(getlatlngFetch, faild, address);
            },600);
        });
    }

    function initialMap() {
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
            return;
          }
        });
    }

    function getlatlngFetch(coordinates){
        lat = coordinates.latitude;
        lng = coordinates.longitude;
        alert("Lattitude= "+lat+"  Longitude= "+lng);
    }

function faild(){
    alert('Failed');
}
```

**This code will work for cordova mobile application development.**
**Download forwardGeocode plugin from** https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder